# How to remove values of an array type column based on another column in a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have two columns in a df: one is a date and the other is an array of dates.

Sample row:

```
Date: 2020-03-01, 
Array_of_dates: ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01']
```

How do I create another column that excludes values of the array that are smaller than `Date` and then returns the minimum date that remains (read: smallest higher value than 'Date').

This would be the result:

```
Date: 2020-03-01, 
Array_of_dates: ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01']
Smallest_higher_date: 2020-04-01
```

I found the `array_remove` function, but as far as I have seen it only allows for exlusion of specific values and doesn't allow for calculations.

Comment: try: `df.selectExpr("*", "filter(Array_of_dates, d -> d >= Smallest_higher_date) as result")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a udf to implement a function and pass it two columns.

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
  'dates_after_date', 
  udf(
    lambda date, dates: [d for d in dates if d > date], 
    ArrayType(StringType())
  )('date', 'array_of_dates')
)
```